# Происхождение слова катран

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова, жаргон

Я задавал вопрос по поводу "каталы" и в одном из ответов выявилась связь со словом "катран", но "катала" для русского языка созвучно, а вот "катран" явно иностранного происхождения. В связи с этим возникает вопрос об очевидности того, что это однокоренные слова. Знает ли кто-нибудь из участников форума что-либо о происхождении слова "катран", помимо того, что это акула и растение?

Comment: @Сашка-дурак, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: В турецком языке так же есть это слово. Там оно имеет 2 значения: 1. Смола. 2. Тара.

Comment: Уточнить надо - это деготь, а на экспорт в бочках, катать можно.
А еще есть английское cutter, в 18 веке легкое парусно-гребное одномачтовое судно, шлюпка, для перевозки грузов и пассажиров и принадлежащее кораблю.

Comment: В  турецком  языке  не  это  слово,  а  так  же  звучащее -  омоним.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря ответам всех участникам, я, наконец, решил для себя эту проблему: происхождение слов **катала** и **катран**. Из Турции на кораблях возили бочки с дёгтем именно их и называли катранами, а моряки в трюмах играли на этих бочках в кости и в карты(вспомните выражение: **деньги на бочку!**), так и вошло в обиход название играющей компании - катран, которое впоследствии переместилось и на сушу, к примеру, через одесский порт, где уже русскоговорящий люд дал определение и самим играющим - каталы.  Наверняка, именно поэтому **катала** для русского языка выглядит более естественно, нежели **катран**.
P.S. Всех участников форума, а также посетителей с Новым годом! Исполнения желаний и интересных открытий!

Answer (score 1):

В связи с акулой: катран - от "кедрон" - колючий. Катраны - колючие акулы, у них под плавником шипы.

Если «колючая акула» – перевод научного латинского термина (хотя так же называют морскую собаку и во многих других странах), то катран – слово греческого происхождения.

В Черном Море издавна, ещё с античных «гомеровских» времен, существовали колонии древних греков, которые были прославленными мореходами и искусными рыбаками. По-гречески одно из названий этой акулы – кедрони, от слова «кедрон», которое значит «острая шишка» или «жало». Кстати, название дерева кедр – отсюда же.

От черноморских греков это же слово попало и в турецкий язык, в котором морскую собаку тоже порою называют катраном.

Answer (score 0):

Катран - это еще и капуста экзотическая. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Катран_приморский 
а воровской катран-похоже, там капусту  и срубают, В смысле бабла. срубил - сut  и деру - run.

Comment: Мало вероятно, что ваша версия истинна, но, безусловно, она интересна. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Этимология  этого  слова  действительно  туманна.  Викисловарь,  например,  выводит  её  из  катран (акула).  Тоже  не  очень  убедительно.  Мне  представляется,  что  это  сленговое  слово  образовано   по  шаблону  "ресторан".  Первая  часть  слова  указывает  на  карточную  игру (катала, катать),  вторая  обозначает  место (  там,  где  играют ).  К  слову  при  ресторанах  такие  комнатки  тоже  существовали.  Это  не  значит,  что  катраны  первоначально  появились  в  ресторанах.  Ресторан  послужил  лишь  образцом  для  нового  слова,  как,  возможно,  слово  хулиган  послужило  образцом  для  слова  уркаган.

Answer (score 0):

"Катран" — это место для взрослой игры, скрытое от посторонних глаз. Сленг.

Answer (score 0):

> В сленг слово «катран» вошло как название подпольного игорного дома.
>
> Катран — маленькое казино для своих, с одной лишь разницей: если в современных казино жульничество практически невозможно, то на катранах в отношении «случайных» посетителей оно было нормой.
>
> Вероятно, термин пришел из городов Поти, Гагры, Кутаиси, где с 70-х годов стало модно быть жуликом. Именно оттуда в Москву и в Ленинград приезжали самые яркие шулеры, те, кто шпилит в карты, — их называли каталами.
>
> <...>
>
> Со своими на катранах, как правило, играли честно. Более того, в статьях дохода от катрана не было позиции «входная плата». Пускали лишь тех, кого знали лично. Зарабатывали с игры, с куража: каждый выигравший считал своим долгом откидывать в сторону хозяина щедрые чаевые. Кроме того, хозяин зарабатывал на спиртном и еде, которую готовили для гостей. Играли в основном в буру; реже — в покер, терц, деберц (родина терца — тюрьма, деберца — еврейские кварталы Одессы).
>
> Лишь изредка на катраны заводили лохов. Их подыскивали в аэропортах и крупных универмагах из числа тех, кто хотел прикупить дефицит. Когда заходил лох, то всех предупреждали, чтобы не спугнули его сленгом и манерами — чтобы не «сел на измену».
>
> С облапошенного простака хозяину платили дополнительно.
>
> <...>
>
> Катраны себя изжили с всеобщим падением запретов и появлением казино.

[Источник](https://document.wikireading.ru/49327)